# SQLite query, wildcards and column values containing % or _ characters

Tags: sql, sqlite, wildcard

In SQLite, I would like to select from a table all the values in a column that contain a `%` character.

For example, given the following table:

```
col1         | col2
-------------+----------------
candidate 1  |  56 %
candidate 2  |  30 %
candidate 3  |  10 percent
...
```

I would like to retrieve the following tuples:

```
candidate 1  |  56 %
candidate 2  |  30 %
```

I don't know how to write the select query given `%` is a wildcard.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col2 LIKE ...%...
```

Same question with the `_` character.

For example, given the following table:

```
col1         | col3
-------------+----------------
candidate 1  |  abc_def
candidate 2  |  ghi
candidate 3  |  klmnop_
...
```

I would like to retrieve the following tuples:

```
candidate 1  |  abc_def
candidate 3  |  klmnop_
```

I don't know how to write the select query given `_` is a wildcard.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col3 LIKE ..._...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the table name is candidate, you can use sqlite keyword `ESCAPE` to escape `%` and `_`, for more references see the sqlite [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like).

```
SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE col2 LIKE '%\%' ESCAPE '\'
```